# How to limit the map in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, locking, limit, zooming

I'm developing my first Android application and it is based partly on displaying some information in Google Maps. I've managed to set a new center point and a new default zoom level (the area I want to display is a city).

Now is it possible to "lock" that new default view somehow? That is, the user should be able to zoom in/out and pan around only within this default area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is not possible to do.

Comment: do you have some official reference/statement that explicitly states this?  I have not found anything myself.  I still want to believe that it can be done.

Comment: What you can do is relocate to a certain area whenever the map changes. But locking the map in the sense I wanted is not possible.